# Android Radio Button Animation

Tags: android

Hello guys I would like to ask a question related to custom radio button. I just designed the radio button with custom background and flip animation. So that when I click radio button it flip and changes background but due to radio button property it first changes background and then animate.Please help me.I want to animate first and then change background.

Thank you

Comment: Do not get discouraged, instead try to explain what you have done, maybe put pictures of the stages, write your code for the animation, and demonstrate exactly at which point you have trouble. This way people can help you, and even in most cases, you yourself can address your own issue.

Remember, you should show initiative in your question. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by code, you can do something like this:

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim./*YOUR ANIMATION*/);

anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
        }           
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
        }           
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            if(ButtonName.isChecked()){
               ButtonName.setImageResource(R.drawable.ImageChecked);
            }else{
               ButtonName.setImageResource(R.drawable.ImageUnchecked);
            }
        }
    });

    ButtonName.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                ButtonName.startAnimation(anim);
            }
        });
```

Comment: ButtonName.setChecked(false); is required in my case and no need to setOnCheckedChangeListener is not required